# ionic 2 ios-sim version not installed after installing XCode 8.1

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, xcode8

I installed ionic2 and ios-sim version 5.0.11 while I had XCode 7.3 Build version 7D175 as shown here:

[image]

After upgrading to Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62, ios-sim version is now 'Not Installed' as shown here:

[image]

I've run and rerun 'sudo npm install -g ios-sim' and verify ios-sim is indeed installed.  However, everytime I run ionic info it shows ios-sim version: Not Installed.  Is ios-sim not needed for XCode 8.1?  Should I ignore this aspect for ionic2?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restart my Mac and after which ios-sim version was found.